Lightning-record-picker, dynamic record filter - not working
i am using record picker to populate Logo. Logo has n sites, when trying to get Sites i see issue.
when dynamic value is provided as criteria filter value, error

This field can't load because of a configuration problem. Ask your Salesforce admin for help.

occurs.
<template>
    <div class="slds-section slds-is-open" style="position: relative"></div>
        <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <lightning-record-picker
                label="Logo"
                placeholder="Search Logo..."
                object-api-name="Account"
                variant="label-hidden"
                icon-name="standard:account"
                value={logo}
                filter={lfilter}
                onchange={handleLogoChange}>
        </lightning-record-picker>
        <lightning-record-picker
            label="Site"
            placeholder="Search Site..."
            object-api-name="Account"
            icon-name="standard:account"
            value={site}
            filter={sfilter}
            onchange={handleSiteChange}>
        </lightning-record-picker>
    </header>
</template>

import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class StringDropdown extends LightningElement {
    @track logo;
    @track site;

    //Logo
    handleLogoChange(event) {
        this.logo = event.detail.recordId;
    }
              
    lfilter = {
        criteria: [
            {
                fieldPath: "Record_Type_Name__c", operator: "eq", value: "Logo"
            }
        ]
    };

    //Site
    sfilter = {
        criteria: [
            {
                fieldPath: "ParentId",
                operator: "eq",
                //value: "0025t00000ehtEmOOW", *-> Works when hardcoded*
                value:  this.logo , *-> Not working*
            }               
        ]
    };

    handleSiteChange(event) {
        this.site = event.detail.recordId;
    }
}

Please suggest, what can be passed to value of sfilter so related sites of logo are populated.

Despite @track, with the current code sfilter is only read once, when the component is rendered. It doesn't react on the change of logo. If a getter is used, a change of a variable mentioned in the getter entails a call of the getter...
get sfilter(){

    return {
        criteria: [
            {
                fieldPath: "ParentId",
                operator: "eq",
                value:  this.logo? this.logo : null
            }
        ]
    };
}

... which will update the second list.
This also ensures value does not become undefined. Opening the Chrome DevTools - for example -, the following Javascript error was written to the console:

ERR_RP005 - Invalid filter configuration. Unsupported filter criteria value: undefined

value is a required field - see "Define Filter Criteria" here, but filtering for "null" is not an issue.
The @track annotation is unnecessary for primitives and can be completely removed. A couple of years ago this was not the case. It is therefore possible there are still some misleading pieces of information online.

Thank you Felix.
when i use get function. i get the below error:
ERR_RP005 - Invalid filter configuration. Malformed filter configuration. Expected an object with a valid criteria property, but got: {}
Please suggest

I'm not sure how your criteria array looks like now, but it should never contain an empty object like the one referred to in the error message: {}. Maybe the best would be for you to start with above code for the get, but hardcode the value of the criteria, so it surely refers to a valid value. And after this worked, to work to make the value dynamic.

this works.
Thanks Felix.
